# I don't understand parameters

Tags: parameters, pseudocode

I have to create a subroutine in which a person's ID is passed as a parameter and displays their other details. Each person is set to a record consisting of name, age, etc. We can assume 'Temp' is user input.

For my start of the code (pseudo-code),

```
BEGIN Siblings(ID)
    Open file FamNames.txt
    Read Temp
    Siblings(FamNames(Temp).ID)
```

Im not sure if this is correct, because one of the fields from the record is called 'ID'. Do I have to rename my parameter or can I leave it how it is and it won't be bad code.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't clash because FamNames(Temp).ID is a property in the text file, meaning that even though it's the same name as the parameter, it shouldn't clash.

Are you trying to do a check for FamNames(Temp).ID == ID? Can you expand on what the end purpose of this software is?